# Probability Theory: Proving an inequality related to permutations with fixed points

Tags: probability, permutations

> Let $\Omega := \mathcal{S}_n$, i.e. the set of permutations of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. We choose a permutation $\sigma \in \Omega$ uniformly at random and let, for each $i \in [n]$, be $A_i$ the event that $\sigma(i) = i$. Show that for all $J \subset \{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $i \in \{1,\ldots,n\} \setminus J$ with $\mathbb{P}\left[A_i \right] >0$ holds
>
> $$\mathbb{P}\left[ \bigwedge_{j \in J} \overline{A_j} \mid A_i \right] \le \mathbb{P}\left[ \bigwedge_{j \in J} \overline{A_j}\right].$$
>
> Hint: Show that this inequality is equivalent to
> $$n \bigg\lvert A_i \wedge \bigwedge_{j \in J} \overline{A_j} \bigg\rvert \le \bigg\lvert \bigwedge_{j \in J} \overline{A_j}\bigg\rvert.$$
> To prove the latter inequality for each permutation $\sigma \in A_i \wedge \bigwedge_{j \in J} \overline{A_j}$, define $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n \in \bigwedge_{j \in J} \overline{A_j}$ and show that $\sigma_k \ne \tau_l$ if $k \ne l$ or $\sigma \ne \tau$.

So far I have the following: For the purported equivalence we first note that $\lvert \Omega \rvert = n!, \lvert A_i \rvert = (n-1)!$ and $\lvert \overline{A_i} \rvert = \lvert \Omega \rvert - \lvert A_i \rvert = n! - (n-1)! = (n-1) \cdot (n-1)!$.

The equivalence now follows by the definition of conditional probability: The direction "$\Longrightarrow$" follows by

\begin{align}
\frac{\bigg\lvert A_i \wedge \bigwedge_{j \in J} \overline{A_j} \bigg\rvert}{(n-1)!} 
&= \frac{\bigg\lvert A_i \wedge \bigwedge_{j \in J} \overline{A_j} \bigg\rvert}{\lvert A_i \rvert} \\
&= \mathbb{P}\left[ \bigwedge_{j \in J} \overline{A_j} \mid A_i \right] \le \mathbb{P}\left[ \bigwedge_{j \in J} \overline{A_j}\right] \\
&= \frac{\bigg\lvert \bigwedge_{j \in J} \overline{A_j} \bigg\rvert}{\lvert \Omega \rvert} \\
&= \frac{\bigg\lvert \bigwedge_{j \in J} \overline{A_j} \bigg\rvert}{n!}
\end{align}

and the direction $"\Longleftarrow"$ follows analogously.

Comment: If you insist on evaluating $\bigg\lvert A_i \wedge \bigwedge_{j \in J} \overline{A_j} \bigg\rvert$ (*which I don't believe is necessary*), assume without loss of generality that $i=n$ and that $J=\{1,2,\dots,k\}$.  Relate this then to simply $\bigg\lvert\bigwedge_{j \in J} \overline{A_j} \bigg\rvert$ where we were talking about permutations of $S_{n-1}$ instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I got that part now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\tau_{u, v}$ denote the transposition between $u$ and $v$, that is,
\begin{align}
\tau_{u, v}(u) &= v
\\
\tau_{u, v}(v) &= u
\\
\tau_{u, v}(w) &= w & \text{if $w \notin\{u, v\}$}.
\end{align}

---

Following the provided hint (with slightly different notation):

Fix $i$ and $J$.

- Show that if $\sigma \in A_i \wedge \bigwedge_{j \in J} \overline{A_j}$, then the $n$ permutations
  $$\tau_{1, i} \sigma, \tau_{2, i} \sigma, \ldots, \tau_{n, i} \sigma$$
  are distinct and each belong to $\bigwedge_{j \in J} \overline{A_j}$. (Hint: simply check that each permutation does not fix $j$.)
- Show that if $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ are distinct permutations in $A_i \wedge \bigwedge_{j \in J} \overline{A_j}$, then $\tau_{k, i} \sigma \ne \tau_{\ell, i} \sigma'$ for any $k, \ell$. (Hint: If $k \ne \ell$, check where each permutation sends $i$. Otherwise if $k = \ell$, use the fact that $\sigma \ne \sigma'$.)
- Why does this prove $n\left| A_i \wedge \bigwedge_{j \in J} \overline{A_j}\right| \le \left|\bigwedge_{j \in J} \overline{A_j}\right|$?